# Parse PFQueryTableView loading User relation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform, relationship

Is it possible to use a PFQueryTableView with a User relation? For example I can easily list user relations (favorited items in this case) in a regular Tableview like so:

```
 PFRelation *relation = [self.currentUser relationForKey:@"favorites"];

[[relation query] findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // There was an error

    } else {
        // NSLog(@"%@", objects);
        salesArray = nil;
        salesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:objects];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

But PFQueryTableView requires you to put in a parseClassName. So would I put in the Users class here then overwrite objectsLoad method or something to obtain a specific logged in users favorites?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was the best solution but I created a Dummy class to avoid PFQueryTableView from automatically downloading data. I basically created an empty Class on Parse named Dummy. Then I just set my objects into `self.objects` and then `[self loadObjects];` to refresh the tableview.